How to calculate payment distribution using PostgreSQL query
I have 2 tables, outstanding and payment.
Outstanding table contains



OutstandingID
OutstandingAmount




1
1000


2
500


3
2000



Payment table contains



PaymentID
PaymentAmount




1
500


2
1000


3
1500


4
500



How to join the two tables to create a distribution table indicating which outstanding ID is paid by which payment ID and by what amount.
Expected distribution



OutstandingID
PaymentID
PaymentAmount




1
1
500


1
2
500


2
2
500


3
3
1500


3
4
500



I can easily achieve this result using a simple loop and calculate the payment balance for each outstanding. But I'm afraid it will be slow for large data. So is there any PostgreSQL query that can calculate this in batch without looping?
